# Multi-tenant based Mysql partitioning - need tenant as first level and second level year and month combo partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am trying to do Multi-tenant based Mysql partitioning - need tenant_code as first level and second level created_at year and month combo partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE `_log` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `message` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `tenant_code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `tenant_code`, `created_at`) USING BTREE
)
```

This is my table

```
ALTER TABLE weekly_audit_log 
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(company_code,YEAR(created_at),MONTH(created_at))(
PARTITION p_01_2019_1 VALUES IN('01',2019,1),
PARTITION p_01_2019_2 VALUES IN('01',2019,2),
PARTITION p_01_2019_3 VALUES IN('01',2019,3),
PARTITION p_01_2019_4 VALUES IN('01',2019,4),
PARTITION p_01_2019_5 VALUES IN('01',2019,5),
PARTITION p_01_2019_6 VALUES IN('01',2019,6),
PARTITION p_01_2019_7 VALUES IN('01',2019,7),
PARTITION p_01_2019_8 VALUES IN('01',2019,8),
PARTITION p_01_2019_9 VALUES IN('01',2019,9),
PARTITION p_01_2019_10 VALUES IN('01',2019,10),
PARTITION p_01_2019_11 VALUES IN('01',2019,11),
PARTITION p_01_2019_12 VALUES IN('01',2019,12),
PARTITION p_01_2020_1 VALUES IN('01',2020,1),
PARTITION p_01_2020_2 VALUES IN('01',2020,2),
PARTITION p_01_2020_3 VALUES IN('01',2020,3),
PARTITION p_01_2020_4 VALUES IN('01',2020,4),
PARTITION p_01_2020_5 VALUES IN('01',2020,5),
PARTITION p_01_2020_6 VALUES IN('01',2020,6),
PARTITION p_01_2020_7 VALUES IN('01',2020,7),
PARTITION p_01_2020_8 VALUES IN('01',2020,8),
PARTITION p_01_2020_9 VALUES IN('01',2020,9),
PARTITION p_01_2020_10 VALUES IN('01',2020,10),
PARTITION p_01_2020_11 VALUES IN('01',2020,11),
PARTITION p_01_2020_12 VALUES IN('01',2020,12));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to give us more information about what you hope to do and what went wrong with your attempt.  And, remember this:  when you solve a problem by partitioning a table into ten chunks, now you have ten problems. Partitioning can harm performance as much as it helps.

Comment: Show us a typical `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I will _probably_ explain why partitioning is a waste of effort.

Comment: This is the table here tenant_code first level and created_at (year and month combo)
CREATE TABLE `log` (
 `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `message` LONGTEXT NULL,
 `tenant_code` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;